# Inspect server/SSL certificate in the current thread only (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, ssl-certificate, webclient

I have a multi-threaded application that connects to many URLs and needs to inspect SSL certs on only certain threads.

I know that I can use `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback` but that works in async mode and across all threads at the same time.

I need need the inspection to happen in the current thread within the synchronous execution of the function that connects to the URL.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a mapping between requests and cert functions like so:

```
// delegate definition for cert checking function
private delegate bool CertFunc(X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors);

// mapping between outbound requests and cert checking functions
private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<HttpWebRequest, CertFunc> _certFuncMap = new ConcurrentDictionary<HttpWebRequest, CertFunc>();

// global cert callback
private static bool ServerCertificateValidationCallback(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
  // call back into the cert checking function that is associated with this request
  var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)sender;
  CertFunc certFunc = _certFuncMap[httpWebRequest];
  return certFunc(certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors);
}
```

Then in the code that's making the requests:

```
// register the global cert callback
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += ServerCertificateValidationCallback;

// create the request object
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUri);

// cert checking function
CertFunc certFunc = (certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) =>
{
  // perform cert logic here
  return true;
};
_certFuncMap[httpWebRequest] = certFunc;

using (var webResponse = httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
{
  // process the response...
}

// clean up the mapping
_certFuncMap.TryRemove(httpWebRequest, out certFunc);
```